# Add an image to one feature within ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, popup

Using the web map pop up config, is there a way to add an image for one asset (polygon)? It appears the only option is to add an image for all the assets in that layer.

Comment: Enable attahcments on the featureclass before publishing. It will show a add attachment option the popup after publishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this solution works: http://arcg.is/1KavGb

I threw it together fairly quickly but the "configure pop-up" feature allows for quite a bit more customization.

My process was this:

1. Create a shapefile in ArcGIS (I use Pro but any desktop version will work).
   Include a text field for the link to a photo hosted on the web.  In this case it is on Wikimedia Commons.
2. Be sure to project the shapefile you create.
3. Upload the zipped shapefile and open it in a map.
4. Configure the pop-up in AGOL by choosing "A custom attribute display" and under "Pop-up media" add the field name where you placed the url in step 1.  (In my case I used {photo}.)

Using this process you could add a photo to any of the features.  If it is just one feature then that is the only one that does not have a null value for the photo attribute.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I found a workaround by first creating a field to contain the link then adding the attachment directly to AGOL and sharing it to generate a URL. Now, the popup doesn't need to be modified and users can click the link next to appropriate field.